# Replace " with \" with Doctrine 1.2

Tags: php, mysql, strip, doctrine-1.2

Here is my problem.

I get data from database using Doctrine 1.2 and put the data in a Textbox.

The data is 19" x 12" to put in the Textbox

**Here is the result:**

```
<input type="text" value="19" x 12"" />
```

I  think I need to escape all the " with \"

My question is :
How can I perform this automaticly without going into all my script and make a str_replace() ?

Thanks everyone.

Comment: Do you have the actual php code your using... I would suggest add_slashes but we need some context. Why are you avoiding using a php function?

Comment: I suppose you asked for solution NOT to go through all your code.
If you fetching data as objects and getting property via and WHENEVER you are taking data you want it escaped you can set getter method. Assuming you get property this way:
`$object->property;`
You set:
`public function getProperty() {
  return htmlspecialchars($this->_get('property'));
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just use [`htmlentities`](http://php.net/htmlentities)

```
$string = htmlentities($text_with_quotes, ENT_QUOTES);
echo '<input type="text" value="' . $string . '">';
```

Should give you what  you need.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [htmlspecialchars](http://nl.php.net/htmlspecialchars), that should solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your function in model class like:

```
public function getInputValue() {
    return addslashes($this->_get('table_field_name'));
}
```

And then use in your views.
Or you can override function that gets data from concrete table field:

```
public function getFieldname() {
    return addslashes($this->_get('table_field_name'));
}
```

addslashes can be replaced by whatever you want to get actually needed data in the views.